# What is the purpose of a short term CD that offers lower interest than a savings account?

Tags: savings-account, certificate-of-deposit

I have noticed that some banks offer short term CDs with interest rates that are actually lower than that that the *same* bank pays on a savings account.

For example Ally bank seems to offer a 0.30% APY for a 3 month CD (up to 0.39% if you deposit $25,000 or more) while their online savings account is offering a 1.05% APY.

What reasons would there be for purchasing such a CD instead of simply parking the money in a savings account?

Comment: Ally offers a loyalty/renewal bonus on CDs.  So when I was building my CD ladder I opened very small 3 month CDs to secure the bonus when they renewed in to my 18 month CDs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very little, as you expected.

The CD locks the rate in, meaning you get the rate *for sure*. The savings account can change any day, so it *could* fall below the CD's rate.
Chances are small, obviously, but it is theoretically possible. If you pay attention, if this happens, you could simply moving it to a CD then (*if* it is still offered).

People with little understanding that want 'security' might be suckered into buying a CD; or there could be versions offered where all the interest comes on the last day (so you delay taxes).

Comment: I suppose delaying taxes could occasionally be useful, but I imagine a situation where it actually saves money overall can't be that common (it seems that it would only be useful if someone needed a place to park money for the later part of a year, and would be paying a _much_ higher taxes if he had the extra income in the current year).